# Grails Redirect Issue with Domain Name Changing

Tags: grails, redirect

I have a Grails application running on, let's say: `www.mysite.com`

In `Config.groovy` I have my `grails.serverURL` set to `www.mysite.com`

I use the `redirect` method to redirect to a certain method, but it always builds up the url using the `grails.serverURL` value, instead of building from the actual URL of the user. I run into a problem when someone visits the site at `mysite.com`, leaving off the `www`. Then, when they click the link that causes the redirect, they are forwarded to `www.mysite.com` which makes them lose their session. What should I be doing differently? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which version of Grails you're using, generally, removing the grails.serverURL from the Config completely will fix that.

Comment: Unfortunately I need it for a plugin. Do you know of anything else I can do? I am using 2.0.3. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What webserver are you using to host the site?

Generally as a rule of thumb I always configure Apache to ensure any non www. calls are redirected to the www. equivalent.

Two lines in the Apache config or a .htaccess is all that is needed, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampledomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exampledomain.co.uk$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Forgot to mention the above is assuming the Apache module mod_rewrite is enabled and turned on (RewriteEngine On)

Comment: do you know how to do this without Apache? I just have Tomcat running for the app. Thanks.