# Grails Preferred (Site) Domain

Tags: tomcat, grails, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have a Grails application and I want to Rewrite my requests to always forward to the "www" version of the site. That is, from "site.com" -> "www.site.com".

I see that I can use Apache to do this, but I am just using Tomcat right now and would prefer to stay that way if possible. Is there anything I can do? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a continuation of [your year old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064567/grails-redirect-issue-with-domain-name-changing)? :-)

Comment: No, they are actually different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [URLRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). It works great.